# How to aggregate by date when a full timestamp is given in aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of errors, so that every error carries a `date` field. How can I aggregate/count/group the errors by DAY only (i.e. exclude the time of the day)? I guess, some smart projection should be applied.

Comment: For future reference it is impportant to define the difference between timestamps and dates, timestamps cannot be used with date functions only date fields. It is just a note because the English threw me off from answering that one then.

Comment: @Sammaye: thanks, the question is fixed.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can do this by using the following aggregation operators:

- [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/)
- [$year](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/year/)
- [$month](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/month/)
- [$dayOfMonth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/dayOfMonth/)

This gives you the error count for each date:

```
db.errors.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id: {
            year : { $year : "$date" },        
            month : { $month : "$date" },        
            day : { $dayOfMonth : "$date" },
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
);
```

This example assumes that the date field in your error documents is `date` and of type [BSON Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date). There is also a Timestamp type in MongoDB, but use of this type is explicitely discouraged by [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#timestamps):

> Note: The BSON Timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use. For most
>   cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON date
>   type. See Date for more information.

Comment: Just a second please - where is the `_id` here? Is it must or (most probably) I am missing something here?

Comment: @BreakPhreak Fixed (I think - again, I can't test it right now)

Comment: PS: as a sidenote, further it can be `$sort`-ed by `_id` (tested as well).

Comment: @Philipp - regarding not using timestamps.. does this mean that we should not use the result of ObjectId.prototype.getTimestamp()?

Comment: @UpTheCreek I was referring to using the BSON timestamp type as a field type when storing documents in the database. You can of course use ObjectId.getTimestamp() on your application layer. But keep in mind that it is the time encoded in the first 4 bytes of the ID hex-string, which should (but doesn't have to) be the time the ObjectId was generated. This might or might not correspond to the time the document was actually inserted into the database.

Answer (score 11):

You can convert your timestamp field to string with specific date format by using [$project (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            newFieldName: {'$dateToString': {format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$yourDateFieldName'}}
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            _id: {newFieldName: '$newFieldName'},
            viewCount: {'$sum': 1}
        }
    }, 
    {'$sort': {'_id.newFieldName': 1}}
], {})
```

Answer (score 6):

Since mongo 2.6 is there [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) function that can be used in `aggregate` like that:

```
db.errors.aggregate([   
 {
   $group : {
    _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" }},
    count: { $sum: 1 }
   }
 }
]);
```