# MongoDB java querying

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I have a question, as I have a collection which stores data. Every record has Date in which was added to collection. My question is: I need to get how many items was added per day.I found some query on MongoDB webpage:

db.orders.find( { ord_dt: { $gt: new Date('01/01/2012') } } ).count()

I'm writing everything in Java and have no idea how to do it. Please be lenient, I have started playing with MongoDB week ago. Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:
I have found mongo aggregating thread on stack overflow in which user wants to count records by minute, as I want to count them for example in every day I suppose it should look like this:

```
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:15" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:19" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:25" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:32" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:45" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:25:15" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:25:15" ) } );

db.so.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        _id: {
            y: { '$year': '$date' },
            m: { '$month': '$date' },
            d: { '$dayOfMonth': '$date' },
        },
        count: { $sum : 1 }
    } } 
] );
```

However have no idea where to start with java implementation. Any advices please? :(

Comment: How should the output look like?

Comment: Output should be just Int, so i want to get number of items added in a particular day (its for a statistics purpose)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657501/how-to-aggregate-by-date-when-a-full-timestamp-is-given-in-aggregation-framework Regarding Java you must read some tutorials, it's easy and you'll manage it.

Comment: A good place to start is the [MongoDB Java driver tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/). If you are looking for a higher level interface, you might want to try using a framework like [Jongo](http://jongo.org/), whose stated goal is "Query in Java as in the Mongo shell".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't you need the date fields also to identify how many items are being added on which date?

```
    final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    final DB db = mongoClient.getDB("DB_NAME");
    final DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME");

    final Map<String, Object> groupIdMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    groupIdMap.put("year", new BasicDBObject("$year", "$date"));
    groupIdMap.put("month", new BasicDBObject("$month", "$date"));
    groupIdMap.put("day", new BasicDBObject("$dayOfMonth", "$date"));

    final DBObject groupIdFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject(groupIdMap));

    groupIdFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
    final DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupIdFields);

    final DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
    projectFields.put("year", "$_id.year");
    projectFields.put("month", "$_id.month");
    projectFields.put("day", "$_id.day");
    projectFields.put("count", 1);
    final DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);

    final AggregationOutput aggregate = collection.aggregate(group, project);
```